# How to make unidirectional @oneToMany relationship for 2 tables using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

My project based on spring boot,Thymeleaf,mysql,html and Jquery.I tried to make a @oneToMany Relation with unidirectional in maintable,but it produces only error like

```
2017-10-23 16:17:49.908 ERROR 18724 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
 resource
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 org.hibernate.AnnotationException: **Unable to map collection
 com.vfraternity.process.entity.EntPropertyMaster.blockListPropSub**   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
 ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
 ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
 ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122)
 ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]  at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
 [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
 [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
 [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
 [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
 [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
 com.vfraternity.VfSpringBootMain.main(VfSpringBootMain.java:12)
 [classes/:na] Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to
 map collection
 com.vfraternity.process.entity.EntPropertyMaster.blockListPropSub     at
 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1604)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:871)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:786)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
 ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:358)
 ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384)
 ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
 ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   ... 16 common frames omitted
 Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find
 column with logical name: propertysubpk in
 org.hibernate.mapping.Table(property_master) and its related
 supertables and secondary tables  at
 org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:831)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:243)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1594)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   ... 31 common frames
 omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find
 column with logical name: propertysubpk in
 org.hibernate.mapping.Table(property_master) and its related
 supertables and secondary tables  at
 org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:826)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   ... 33 common frames
 omitted
```

I tried to achive unidirectional using

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="propertysubfkid", referencedColumnName="propertysubpk")
private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = newArrayList<EntPropertySub>();
```

But it produces only error...
Here is my complete codes..

```
**EntPropertyMaster** 

package com.vfraternity.process.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Entity
@Table(name="Property_Master")
public class EntPropertyMaster implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6162594257264775391L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="propertyid")
private int property_id;
@NotNull
private String property_name;
@NotNull
private String address1;
@NotNull
@Column(columnDefinition="varchar(15) default'None'")
private String address2;
@NotNull
private String city;
@NotNull
private String state;
@NotNull
private String country;
@NotNull
private int zipcode;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="propertysubfkid", referencedColumnName="propertysubpk")
private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = new ArrayList<EntPropertySub>();

@Version
private int version;
private Boolean is_active;
private String created_by;
private Date created_ts;
private String modified_by;
private Date modified_ts;
private String approved_by;
private Date approved_ts;





public EntPropertyMaster() {
    
}
//Getter Setter
public int getProperty_id() {
    return property_id;
}
public void setProperty_id(int property_id) {
    this.property_id = property_id;
}
public String getProperty_name() {
    return property_name;
}
public void setProperty_name(String property_name) {
    this.property_name = property_name;
}
public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}
public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}
public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}
public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}
public Boolean getIs_active() {
    return is_active;
}
public void setIs_active(Boolean is_active) {
    this.is_active = is_active;
}
public String getCreated_by() {
    return created_by;
}
public void setCreated_by(String created_by) {
    this.created_by = created_by;
}
public Date getCreated_ts() {
    return created_ts;
}
public void setCreated_ts(Date created_ts) {
    this.created_ts = created_ts;
}
public String getModified_by() {
    return modified_by;
}
public void setModified_by(String modified_by) {
    this.modified_by = modified_by;
}
public Date getModified_ts() {
    return modified_ts;
}
public void setModified_ts(Date modified_ts) {
    this.modified_ts = modified_ts;
}
public String getApproved_by() {
    return approved_by;
}
public void setApproved_by(String approved_by) {
    this.approved_by = approved_by;
}
public Date getApproved_ts() {
    return approved_ts;
}
public void setApproved_ts(Date approved_ts) {
    this.approved_ts = approved_ts;
}
public int getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}
public void setZipcode(int zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}
public List<EntPropertySub> getBlockListPropSub() {
    return blockListPropSub;
}
public void setBlockListPropSub(List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub) {
    this.blockListPropSub = blockListPropSub;
}
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**EntPropertySub**
package com.vfraternity.process.entity;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name="propertysub")
public class EntPropertySub implements Serializable
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 810618405796553525L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="propertysubpk")
private int propertySub_pk;

@NotNull
private String blockname;
@NotNull
private int floors;
@NotNull
private String flatstart;
private String flatend;

@Version
private int version;
private Boolean is_active;
private String created_by;
private Date created_ts;
private String modified_by;
private Date modified_ts;
private String approved_by;
private Date approved_ts;

public EntPropertySub() {
    
}


//Getter Setter
public int getPropertySub_pk() {
    return propertySub_pk;
}
public void setPropertySub_pk(int propertySub_pk) {
    this.propertySub_pk = propertySub_pk;
}
public String getBlockname() {
    return blockname;
}
public void setBlockname(String blockname) {
    this.blockname = blockname;
}
public int getFloors() {
    return floors;
}
public void setFloors(int floors) {
    this.floors = floors;
}
public String getFlatstart() {
    return flatstart;
}
public void setFlatstart(String flatstart) {
    this.flatstart = flatstart;
}
public String getFlatend() {
    return flatend;
}
public void setFlatend(String flatend) {
    this.flatend = flatend;
}
public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}
public Boolean getIs_active() {
    return is_active;
}
public void setIs_active(Boolean is_active) {
    this.is_active = is_active;
}
public String getCreated_by() {
    return created_by;
}
public void setCreated_by(String created_by) {
    this.created_by = created_by;
}
public Date getCreated_ts() {
    return created_ts;
}
public void setCreated_ts(Date created_ts) {
    this.created_ts = created_ts;
}
public String getModified_by() {
    return modified_by;
}
public void setModified_by(String modified_by) {
    this.modified_by = modified_by;
}
public Date getModified_ts() {
    return modified_ts;
}
public void setModified_ts(Date modified_ts) {
    this.modified_ts = modified_ts;
}
public String getApproved_by() {
    return approved_by;
}
public void setApproved_by(String approved_by) {
    this.approved_by = approved_by;
}
public Date getApproved_ts() {
    return approved_ts;
}
public void setApproved_ts(Date approved_ts) {
    this.approved_ts = approved_ts;
}
}
```

Please help me to solve this..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is:

> **Unable to find column with logical name: propertysubpk in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(property_master)**

The reason is that you have the `referencedColumnName` attribute wrong. It is supposed to be:

> **JPA 2.1 11.1.25:** The name of the column referenced
>   by this foreign key column. When
>   used with entity relationship mappings
>   other than the cases described below, **the
>   referenced column is in the table of the target
>   entity**. When used with a unidirectional
>   OneToMany foreign key mapping, the referenced
>   column is in the table of the
>   source entity. When used inside a Join-
>   Table annotation, the referenced key column
>   is in the entity table of the owning
>   entity, or inverse entity if the join is part of
>   the inverse join definition. When used in a
>   collection table mapping, the referenced
>   column is in the table of the entity containing
>   the collection.

To explain: a `@JoinColumn` creates a column in the *many* side of the relation (the `EntPropertySub` here) with the given name that references the *PK* of the parent entity, unless `referencedColumnName` is specified. In the latter case the FK in the "many" table references the column given in `referencedColumnName`. In your case you want to reference the PK of `EntPropertyMaster`, so `referencedColumnName` is redundant. Simply use:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="propertysubfkid")
private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = newArrayList<EntPropertySub>();
```

Comment: it works,but it does not create a sperate column in Master table why?But my need is a physical column is also need to create in master table to refer a sub table...please explain in code..Thank you buddy

Comment: Why do you want to create a column in the master table? The way 1-many relations work (1 is the master and many is the subtable) is that a FK column is placed in the subtable referencing the PK of the master table.

Comment: not in master ,but need to create in child table,then only possible to identitfy it which data is refered to master table...Thats why..Please check my answer i updated it...

Answer (score 1):

Try this: make sure how the foreign key in the table EntPopertySub called

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="propertyid")
private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = new ArrayList<EntPropertySub>();
```

It's not possible to create a physical column on the master table because you have a OneToMany relation. OneToMany means that Master has many Sub Table references.

Let's explain the Problem:

If you would have a column in the master table you need to would add a list of references in one cell.

For Example

`------------------
 |  sub-fk  |
 |1, 2, 3, 4| <-- and this is against the database normalization`

But this is not necessary:

Hibernate will automatically select all the referenced sub-columns for you (intern hibernate joins to the columns)

If you use the entitymanager to select the master data, the sub-data is included in the List blockListPropSub attribute

Comment: it works,but it does not create a sperate column in Master table why?But my need is a physical column is also need to create in master table to refer a sub table...please explain in code..Thank you buddy

Comment: I have updated the post. I hope you can understand it.

Comment: yaa you are telling right,but we can create a master table reference to child table is possible..so finnaly i made it in this code "@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)"
 "@JoinColumn(name="propertyidfk")"
 private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = new ArrayList<EntPropertySub>();   It will create column in child table,but i wrote this code in parent Entity...Please Note we need to give unique name not a primarykey column name of child /parent table..Then only it create a seperate column in child table,Because we are using OneToMany Relationship...

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly shows mapping missing in your schema relation.

You need to map `EntPropertyMaster` in `EntPropertySub`.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="entPropertyMaster")
private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = newArrayList<EntPropertySub>();
```

Provide `EntPropertyMaster` mapping in relation entity too.i.e.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="entPropertyMasterId",referencedColumnName="id")
private EntPropertyMaster entPropertyMaster;
```

> Relationships in JPA are always unidirectional, unless you associate
>   the parent with the child in both directions. Cascading REMOVE
>   operations from the parent to the child will require a relation from
>   the parent to the child (not just the opposite).

Comment: Hmm.. with this solution he will provide bidirectional mapping

Comment: Thanks for reply buddy,still got error...Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like "@"JoinTable or "@"JoinColumn: com.vfraternity.process.entity.EntPropertyMaster.blockListPropSub ...i made a code like OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="EntPropertyMaster")

Comment: @mimu1011 No both entity is not dependent on each other. there is only one-way traffic. second entity taking reference to just map other entity

Comment: @VigneshR you need to add mapping entity in EntPropertySub model

Comment: which makes that in bidirectional right?...i cant understand..can u please explain in code what i need to make changes ?

Comment: @VigneshR https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/03/29/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ a very good article

Comment: @HarshalPatil Sure. you provide bidirectional mapping if you add the reference in the associated class. I cann access the "Parent" from "Child" too

Answer (score 0):

When you use the @JoinColumn on a @OneToMany relationship, the `name` attribute will point to the relating tables column, that is `EntPropertySub` entity and the `referencedColumnName` should be pointing to the column of the entity in which the @OneToMany annotation is present, that is `EntPropertyMaster`.

So basically you have it other way round and it should be in my opinion:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="propertysubpk", referencedColumnName="propertysubfkid")
private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = newArrayList<EntPropertySub>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly i got a answer..

i made a changes in master entity **"EntPropertyMaster"**

```
"@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)"
"@JoinColumn(name="propertyidfk")"  
private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = new ArrayList<EntPropertySub>();
```

It will create column in child table,but i wrote this code in parent Entity...

> Please Note we need to give unique name for column creation,Then only it creates a column in child table.... not a primarykey column name
>   of child /parent table..